# Spring session with in memory store

Tags: spring, spring-session

Why does not spring.session.store-type has in memory option. ?

Is there any way to use spring session with in memory option without writing my implementation of store ?

I would like to use spring session for rest api with token

```
 @Bean
  public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
    return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
  }
```

Answer (score 18):

I found solution, there is a MapSessionRepository  which can accept map.
here is a documentation  [EnableSpringHttpSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#api-enablespringhttpsession)

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
@Configuration
public class SpringHttpSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great!  We use spring-session with redis but not for local testing so catalina.session.StandardSession was being used.  With your code, I can use HttpSession without needing redis and it's much better for testing.

Comment: [Updated Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/config/annotation/web/http/EnableSpringHttpSession.html)